# Import JavaScript file from within JavaScript synchronously?

Tags: javascript, dom

Instead of messing up my HTML file, I'd like to import my external JavaScript files through another JavaScript file, much like `@import` in css.

On several websites, including StackOverflow itself, I noticed that appending a script tag to the DOM can solve this issue; however, this is done asynchronuosly, while the order of my files is important - the second file for example may rely on the first file in the list. When, say, loading jQuery first and then loading a dependency (plugin etc.) of it, the dependency might finish loading earlier and will throw errors because jQuery doesn't exist yet.

Therefore, this does not seem to be an option. How can I **synchronously** load JavaScript files from within another JavaScript file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot synchronously load JS files from within JS.

What you **can** do however, is implement a loader queue, something like this:

```
function ScriptLoader(queue) {
   this.started = false;
   this.queue = queue || [];
   this.currentIndex = 0;
   var self = this;
   this.next = function() {
     if(self.currentIndex == self.queue.length) return;
     self.load(self.queue[self.currentIndex]);
     self.currentIndex++;
   };
   this.load = function(dest) {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.src = dest;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
      s.onload = self.next;
      if('onreadystatechange' in s) {
        s.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
             self.next();
          }
        }
      }
   };
}

ScriptLoader.prototype.start = function() {
    if(!this.started) {
       this.next();
       this.started = true;
    }
};


var loader = new ScriptLoader(['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js', 'http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js']);
loader.start();
```

In the above example, `jQuery` is loaded first, then `jQuery UI`, then the Twitter JS widget. :)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about a loader queue does and what an implementation might look like?  I'm interested in this question as well.

Comment: Thanks, that is an ingenious way. Thanks. (A litle typo by the way, you end the array with two brackets.)

Comment: @Jacob Do this: `this.queue = queue || [];` to avoid defining a global variable.

Comment: @Jacob Also, I think you need to append those SCRIPT elements to the BODY.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I'm appending them to the HEAD. :P

Comment: @Jacob And shouldn't the increment be postfix, not prefix?

Comment: You can improve it by loading them async and then executing them in order like some other libraries do.

Comment: @Jason Zhekov Is that not what I'm doing?

Comment: +1 This is awesome -- Does anyone know if this is how Google's script loader works?

Comment: I meant downloading them in parallel.

Comment: @Jason Zhekov I guess I could do that, but then you'd possibly run into race conditions with dependencies....

Comment: When looking at the other answer provided, LABjs can do this easily. It has a developer-friendly way of deciding what to load in parallel, while everything is downloaded asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [LABjs](http://labjs.com/) for **asynchronous** loading of scripts. I would recommend using one of these libraries instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I'm afraid that this will cause errors as mentioned in my question. Edit: I see that they also support synchronous loading with certain functions, I'm sorry. It looks really useful, thanks.

Comment: LABjs (and RequireJS) don't support "synchronous loading" per se, but they do support parallel loading but serial execution (to preserve dependency execution order), which is what you need.